# Opera: cannot save additional Gmail login details in wand

Tags: opera, password-management

I have a couple of gmail accounts that I log in to using Opera's wand. The problem is that I cannot save login details for any additional accounts: the wand save password dialog never pops up, instead I'm just logged in into Gmail. Is there a limit on how many passwords you can save for a domain?

I'm using Opera 11.11 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press ALT+F11 for toggle to classic menu view. Then go to Tools-Advanced-Password manager. Type "google" to searchbox. You will see all logins associated to pages where Opera should and shouldn't remember password. If you do not see login next to record, it means Opera should never remember password for this site. These records you should delete if you want to change this behaviour.